# Send http-404 response BUT dont send custom error page setted in IIS server | PHP

Tags: php, iis, custom-error-pages

Lets understand the scenario:

:- Using PHP for a web application on IIS 8.5

:- A custom error page is set for 404 with following web-config snippt:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/path/404.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

:- This is working for non-existing page **and IIS also** return this 404.php if I set header to 404 (via `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404); die;`) in any PHP page.

**Question:**

Now, I wan to send 404 http response code in some php-file on any specific condition, lets say if database returns 0 rows. I can do that by setting header as above but that will return the custom error page also. *Is there any way to send 404 code and tell IIS to send response as it is, without sending custom error page along with it?*

**Issues:**

:- If I remove custom error page and put the content between `header()` and `die()` then it will meet my requirement but IIS will fail to serve custom error on pages which actually doesn't exist.

:- I am using URL rewrite so that cannot use multiple custom error pages based on `location` tag and don't want to redirect to any suggested different URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have one tricky solution/idea, I want to share that also. But if anybody have any better solution, I welcome and thanks to them.

**Trick/Solution/Idea:**

> *Step 1:-* From any existing php-page set a `session variable` just before `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);` and put a specific message in that variable(I suggest to use different integer code as session variable's value for different php-pages) THEN set header and call `die(); or exit;`.
>
> *Step 2:-* After that IIS or any other server will execute custom error page. SO, in custom error page check the session variable and echo content as follows....
>
> ........2a - If session variable is not set then display "*normal error content with main menu*" etc.
>
> ........2b - If session variable is set then check the value and according to value display the different content you want to show to user like: "*data not found message and search panel*"

**Note:** In custom error page's coding you again need to set 404 header, and ALSO you can send different error code according to session variable's value in above trick.